# Nuxt running on port domain.com:49000, how could I run it on domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt js to host on a vps.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "nuxtjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt --hostname example.com --port 49000",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "deploy": "pm2 start npm --name nuxtjs -- start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@yeger/vue-masonry-wall": "^3.0.16",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "pm2": "^5.1.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "config":{
    "nuxt":{
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": "49000"
    }
  }
}
```

And I run the script: `npm run deploy`. This start the server on `example.com:49000`, now instead of running on this port how could I run it on `example.com`.

I have tried to add .htaccess as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) http://example.com:49000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com:49000/$1 [P,L]
```

but it gives me error on `http://example.com` as:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80
```

Comment: HTTP's port is 80, HTTPS's port is 443 but in either cases, you don't need to specify the port nor the hostname. Expose it with your Apache/Nginx server on the build directory.

Comment: could you please suggest how to do it?